# ParserError in Pandas read caused by negative values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read in a csv using pandas with the following code.

```
  newDF = pd.read_csv(updatePath,sep='\s*',parse_dates=[[0,1,2,3]],index_col=0,
                            header=None,engine='python')
```

However I get the following error:

ParserError: Expected 20 fields in line 4, saw 21. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.

The error is caused by the first occurrence of a negative value.

```
2018 01 01 00   0.33
2018 01 01 01   0.30
2018 01 01 02   0.12
2018 01 01 03  -0.30
```

How can i read in the CSV to incorporate the negative values without getting ther parser error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can do it by changing the regex pattern to use, from **`\s*`** to **`\s+`** :

```
newDF = pd.read_csv(
    "test2.csv",
    sep='\s+',
    parse_dates=[[0,1,2,3]],
    index_col=0,
    header=None,
    engine='python')
```

Output:

```
                        4
0_1_2_3                  
2018-01-01 00:00:00  0.33
2018-01-01 01:00:00  0.30
2018-01-01 02:00:00  0.12
2018-01-01 03:00:00 -0.30
```